# Connectedness in Measure Preserving Ergodic Systems

Tags: general-topology, ergodic-theory

In topology a space $X$ is called connected if there is no partition of $X=A\cup B$, that $A$ and $B$ are open. Since ergodic systems have the property that each trajectory visits any neighbourhood of any point in state space infinitely many times it appears to me that the state space of an ergodic system should be connected (and maybe even path connected ). Is there such a theorem for it or can somebody give a counter-example please?

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer below I realised that I forgot to mention 
the extra assumption of a continuous $T$ on this ergodic system.

Comment: Lee's example is clearly continuous.

Comment: @studiosus, I am not following. The dynamics of the system is discrete in Lee's example

Comment: Oh, I see that you meant a flow.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample. Start with $f : S^1 \to S^1$ being a rotation through an angle $\phi$ which is an irrational multiple of $\pi$:
$$f(\exp(i \theta)) = \exp(i(\theta + \phi))$$
This is ergodic with respect to the angle measure. Now remove the orbit of one point, say the orbit of $0$, so the map $f$ is being restricted to the set
$$X = S^1 - \{\exp(i k \phi) \,\, | \,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
Since the subset being removed is countable, it has measure zero, and therefore the restriction of $f$ to $X$ is still ergodic with respect to the restriction of the angle measure. But $X$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: Thanks vote up, nice example but I forgot to put an assumption which was related to the part that I said it should be path connected. $T$ should be continuous...

Comment: $T$, or $f$ restricted to $X$ as I am referring to it, is indeed a continuous function. The restriction of a continuous function to a subset is always continuous. Unless you are using the term "continuous" in some other manner, as in the 2nd comment of studious to your question?

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. I mean that the mapping is without discrete timesteps but rather a continuous one.

Answer (score 1):

With the amended formulation the answer is: X is always connected (since it contains a dense connected subset), but need not be path connected (just suspend Lee's example).

Edit: Suppose you have a continuous dynamical system (a flow), which is a continuous map $F: X\times {\mathbb R}\to X$. Then ergodicity of $F$ implies that almost every trajectory is dense in $X$. Every trajectory is clearly connected. If a topological space $X$ contains a dense connected subset $Y$ then $X$ is connected (follows from the definition).

For path connectivity question: Every homeomorphism $f: Z\to Z$ admits a "suspension flow" $F$ on the mapping torus $X$ of $f$. If $f$ is ergodic, so is $F$. In Lee's example, $Z$ is totally disconnected and uncountable, hence, the mapping torus $X$ is not path-connected.

**Edit.** The suspension flow is a standard construction which allows one to relate discrete and continuous dynamics. Suppose that $f: Z\to Z$ is a homeomorphism. Recall that the *mapping torus* $M_f$ of $f$ is the quotient
$$
Z\times [0,1]/\sim
$$
where $(z,0)\sim (f(z), 1)$. If $Z$ is equipped with a measure $\mu$, you take the product measure $\mu \times Leb$ and push it forward to $M_f$, where $Leb$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. The result is a measure $\nu$ on $M_f$ (of the same total mass as $\mu$).

The mapping torus $M_f$ is foliated by the lines each of which is the union of projections of the segments of the type $z\times [0,1]$. For each of these lines you have the vector field $V$ which is the projection of the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ on the segments $z\times [0,1]$, where $0\le t\le 1$ is the natural coordinate on $[0,1]$. The flow $F_t$ of this vector field is the *suspension flow* of $f$. I think, this construction should be in the book by Katok and Hasselblatt.

Note that $Z$ embeds homeomorphically in $M_f$ via the map $z\mapsto z\times 0\to M_f$. The relation between the dynamics of $f$ and of $F_t$ is via the following: Points $x, y\in Z$ are in the same orbit of $f$ if and only if their images in $M_f$ are in a common flow line of the flow (leaf of the foliation). If $f$ was preserving the measure $\mu$ then $F_t$ preserves $\nu$. If $(Z,\mu,f)$ is ergodic, so is $(M_f, \nu, F_t)$. (This is immediate from the definitions.)

Comment: Can you please refer to some reference for a proof? Aditionally and as I have asked what about the case where you have continuous flows rather than map?

Comment: @Cupitor: I was answering the revised question about flows. What part of my answer was unclear?

Comment: I am so sorry for my late reply. Thank you for clarifying. Although I don't know what is `suspension flow`. Could you please explain?